# Xubuntu 17.10: keyboard shortcut for either tiling window or moving display

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, window-manager, xfwm4

I'm running Xubuntu 17.10. I've managed to configure keyboard
shortcuts to tile windows either to the right or to the left using
<kbd>s-right</kbd> and <kbd>s-left</kbd>. However, I have multiple
display and what I would really like is to replicate the behaviour
later versions of Windows: if a window is already tiled to the left
when I press <kbd>s-left</kbd> then it should be moved to the display
on the left. But I cannot even find any shortcut for moving the window
to another display.

Is there any simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

you can move a window to another display with `super+shift+arrow` depending on how you configured your displays. If the other display is on the right, you would use `super+shift+right` to get the active window there